# VSCode Settings Sync: how to see previous versions of my `settings.json`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've just changed my VSCode settings while having the Settings Sync (built-in feature) turned on. How do I see that change?

I would expect that clicking the `settings.json` file in the sidebar would show the diff but it doesn't do anything for me:

[image: VSCode sidebar]

Answer (score 0):

If you click the ones below it with something like `8 minutes ago` it'll open a diff.

Comment: Clicking that also does nothing. I'm not sure what's expected, it might be [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129129#issuecomment-884705960)?!

Comment: I guess it is a bug. Sorry.